# django related_name doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have complex model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  names = models.ManyToManyField('Name')
  wives = models.ManyToManyField('Person',related_name='husbands',null = True, blank = True)
```

And Form:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  names_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(names_set__id=2), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))
  wives_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(husbands__id=2), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))

     class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('names','wives')
        widgets = {
         'names' : forms.HiddenInput(),
         'wives': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

Unfortunately - for unknown reasons - wives works, names_set - don't. I tried to add related_name:

```
names = models.ManyToManyField('Name', related_name='name_owners')

But not. The Error is: 
FieldError at /mysite/edit/2/
Cannot resolve keyword 'name_owners' into field. Choices are: husbands, id, names, wives
```

I'm refactoring code (earlier name was just a text) What I forgot to change?

```
Trackback:
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: 

Django Version: 1.7.7
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

)
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  224.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/excursor/frontoffice/views.py" in <module>
  35. class DiggerForm(ModelForm):
File "/home/excursor/frontoffice/views.py" in DiggerForm
  139.   names_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(,queryset=Person.objects.filter(names_set__id=2), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  691.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  709.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1331.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1358.                     current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1182.         lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1120.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1427.             self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in raise_field_error
  1433.                          "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at 
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'names_set' into field. Choices are:  husbands, id, names, wives
```

Comment: Can you post full error text?

Comment: It looks like you are not doing a reverse relationship here.

Comment: Make sure your code is consistent everywhere. Above I can see `name_set`, `name_owners` and `names`. Look at the full traceback, it will tell you the line where the problem is.

Comment: As others have asked, please post a full traceback, as well as the the code which is generating this error. At a guess, however, I would say that you need to use `names`. The error that you posted gives you a hint to that effect: `Choices are: husbands, id, names, wives`

Comment: @Alasdair - It is consistent - automaticaly related_name for names should be names_set. name_owners is my try to add own related_name

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm names__id=2 will show name with id =2. names_set__id=2 will show names, where person id is equal 2. It works for wives/husband.

Comment: @karthikr the only difference for me, is that wives are related to the same class Person, and Names - not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `related_name` works.

`Person.objects.filter()` will always return people, not names.

If you want a queryset of names, then do

```
Name.objects.filter(person=2)
```

That will return names linked to the person with id 2 (you don't need `__id` because id is the primary key.

The reason that your code is working for husbands/wives is that the field links to the same model.

Comment: Now I understand...This was a coincidence... I have to edit your post, because empiricism shows that this is good solution